# Auslogics Disk Defrag SSD Support

Tags: ssd, defragment, trim

I am using Auslogics Disk Defrag in my computer to defrag my drives. Recently, I change my main system drive into an SSD. I then enabled the TRIM feature in its SSD support settings. **Question is, if it's enabled, does the Auslogics defrag my solid state drives using TRIM method or it's just applicable with the SSD Optimize?**

Comment: let the Windows inbox tool and don't use any 3rd party tools where you don't know what they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSD's should not be fragmented in the 'normal' ways, as they do not have the same characteristics as Spinning Disk drives.

If the software has an SSD setting, use that.

'Defragmenting' SSDs in the 'normal' way actually causes more wear on the sectors, and thus will cause premature failure of the disk, and give you no performance boost.

---

A few points to note :-

Fragmentation is where data on the disk is saved in different areas (called sectors) on the disk. Over time, data gets moved around and jumbled up. The more the data is used, the more fragmentation occurs.

Fragmentation is the process of collecting data that should be together, and saving it to the same part of the disk.

Fragmentation is a performance issue on Spinning Disks, as the 'first' part of the disk is faster to access than the 'last' part of the disk, because the device that actually does the reading has to move across the disk surface, which takes time. Data that resides in different sectors of the disk (ie fragmented), then takes more and more time to read.

SSD's don't have this varying seek time across different areas of the disk, as there are no moving parts. This means that data that is distributed across different sectors, doesn't take any longer than any other sectors.